# Core Text examples for iPhone/iPad

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am looking for a Core Text example for iphone/ipad but with little luck. Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: What KennyTM said is true. Remember, however, that the OS 3.2 is still under developer NDA, and you may not discuss specifics in public fora. The Apple Developer Forum is probably your best bet.

Comment: check this:
http://github.com/jonasschnelli/I7CoreTextExample

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have written a small project on Github that provides an Objective-C wrapper for Core Text:
https://github.com/akosma/CoreTextWrapper
In particular, it takes any string and renders it over multiple pages, with multiple columns each page.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can find an example of column layout tweaked to work with iPhone/iPad here:
http://foobarpig.com/iphone/coretext-example-column-layout-with-correctly-inverted-text.html

Answer (score 1):

Core Text is a public framework on the Mac OS X. Any examples that work on the Mac, should be usable on the iPhone/iPad too.

See [Core Text Programming Guide: Common Operations](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Operations/Operations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533-CH4-SW1).

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a class named [OHAttributedLabel](http://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel/) to create a UILabel that can draw NSAttributedString. This class uses CoreText for the whole rendering part, you can use this as a start if needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can find column layout with images in this post: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/how-to-create-a-simple-magazine-app-with-core-text