# How do I display a NSAttributedString on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, nsattributedstring

I believe I understand how to set NSAttributedString values but how on earth do you actually display them in the interface?

examples: UILabel, UITextView, etc.

Specific instructions would be greatly appreciated/

- Thanks!

Comment: You can also use the OHAttributedLabel class, you can [find it here](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel/). HTH

Answer (score 2):

you could also create a CATextLayer, which works fine with attributed strings...
Just create the layer, and set it's string property...

Have fun... :D

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to bother with CATextLayer, you should check out [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/). It's just like UILabel, except that supports NSAttributedStrings (using the same setText: method as UILabel, so you can use it as a drop-in replacement)

Answer (score 2):

> In iOS 6 and later you can use attributed strings to display formatted
>   text in text views, text fields, and some other controls. Both AppKit
>   and UIKit also define extensions to the basic attributed string
>   interface that allows you to draw their contents in the current
>   graphic context.

[NSAttributedString Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

The controls you mentioned only work with strings, not attributed strings. The only way to display them is to do a lot of work with Core Text. File a complaint with bugreporter.apple.com to request they flesh this part of UIKit out.

Comment: I'll be sure to file a bug report.

Could you please point me in the direction of an example or tutorial of using Core Text to display an attributed string?

Thanks :)

Comment: A simple two-second search provides a few answers on this site alone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446975/core-text-examples-for-iphone-ipad